# Binding a property of code behind xaml page to list view

Tags: wpf, xaml, listview, xamarin.forms

I try to use a public static property named "People" in the code behind of a xaml page and it is filled in the constructor of the code behind page.  Then in xaml page, I let that public property bound to ItemsSource of Xamarin.Forms ListView widget. But on running it, I do not see the listview items are filled. There are nothing to be shown for that listview.  What am I doing wrong here? Please help.

I guess the constructor of the code behind page class is bound AFTER the data rendering for items of the listview. But I am not sure

Codes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Mvvm2.Mvvm2Page"
             x:Name="page">
  <ContentPage.Padding>
    <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Thickness" iOS="0,20,0,0" />
  </ContentPage.Padding>


  <Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="0"></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>



    <ListView x:Name="listViewPeople" HasUnevenRows="True" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Header="People List" 
              ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Reference page}, Path=People}">

      <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <ViewCell>
            <ContentView Padding="5">
              <Frame OutlineColor="Accent" Padding="10">
                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                  <StackLayout>
                    <Label Text="{Binding Id}"></Label>
                    <Label Text="{Binding FirstName}"></Label>
                    <Label Text="{Binding LastName}"></Label>
                    <Label Text="{Binding Age}"></Label>
                  </StackLayout>
                </StackLayout>
              </Frame>
            </ContentView>
          </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
      </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
  </Grid>
</ContentPage>


using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace Mvvm2
{
    public partial class Mvvm2Page : ContentPage
    {
        public static List<Person> People; // public static property

        public Mvvm2Page()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            // fill property "People"
            People = new List<Person>();
            People = getPeople();
        }


        private List<Person> getPeople()
        {
            var list = new List<Person>();

            var p1 = new Person { Id = 1, Age = 19, FirstName = "Anna", LastName = "Larson" };
            var p2 = new Person { Id = 2, Age = 23, FirstName = "Beri", LastName = "Slovik" };
            var p3 = new Person { Id = 3, Age = 65, FirstName = "Ron", LastName = "Prelosi" };
            var p4 = new Person { Id = 4, Age = 32, FirstName = "William", LastName = "Maxel" };
            var p5 = new Person { Id = 5, Age = 71, FirstName = "Fred", LastName = "Lipez" };
            var p6 = new Person { Id = 6, Age = 44, FirstName = "Dave", LastName = "Vanoviz" };


                    list.Add(p1);
                    list.Add(p2);
                    list.Add(p3);
                    list.Add(p4);
                    list.Add(p5);
                    list.Add(p6);

            return list;
        }
    }
}

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Mvvm2
{
    public class Person
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 3):

The expression

```
public static List<Person> People; // public static property
```

does not declare a property, but a field.

What you need here is a non-static public property:

```
public static List<Person> People { get; set; }
```

In case the value of the property may later change, you should create a view model class that declares the property, and implements the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface:

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private List<Person> people;
    public List<Person> People
    {
        get { return people; }
        set
        {
            people = value;
            OnNotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(People));
        }
    }

    private void OnNotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

You would assign an instance of this class to the DataContext of your Page

```
InitializeComponent();
var viewModel = new ViewModel();
viewModel.People = getPeople();
DataContext = viewModel;
```

and write the binding in XAML as

```
ItemsSource="{Binding People}"
```

If you later want to set the People property of the view model you can simply access it via the DataContext property like

```
((ViewModel)DataContext).People = getPeople();
```

or you just store the ViewModel instance in a class member.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I will try your solution.

Answer (score -1):

please try with ObservableCollection

defind a property like this

```
public ObservableCollection<People> Peoples { get; set; }
```

then in your constructory

```
Peoples=new ObservableCollection<People>();

 var p1 = new Person { Id = 1, Age = 19, FirstName = "Anna", LastName = "Larson" };
            var p2 = new Person { Id = 2, Age = 23, FirstName = "Beri", LastName = "Slovik" };
            var p3 = new Person { Id = 3, Age = 65, FirstName = "Ron", LastName = "Prelosi" };
            var p4 = new Person { Id = 4, Age = 32, FirstName = "William", LastName = "Maxel" };
            var p5 = new Person { Id = 5, Age = 71, FirstName = "Fred", LastName = "Lipez" };
            var p6 = new Person { Id = 6, Age = 44, FirstName = "Dave", LastName = "Vanoviz" };




                    Peoples.Add(p1);
                    Peoples.Add(p2);
                    Peoples.Add(p3);
                    Peoples.Add(p4);
                    Peoples.Add(p5);
                    Peoples.Add(p6);
```